# Error 414 -The requested URL is too large to process

Tags: api, charts

I am using Google Chart API in my Application and generating graph using URL "http://chart.apis.google.com"

I am getting error **"The requested URL is too large to process"**, when I provide large set of parameters to this URL.

What I can do in this situation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Google Charts API FAQ](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/image/faq.html#url_length) offers this advice:

> **Is there a limit on the URL length for the Google Chart API? What is the maximum URL length?**
>
> The maximum length of a URL is not determined by the Google Chart API, but rather by web browser and web server considerations. The longest URL that Google accepts in a chart GET request is 2048 characters in length, after URL-encoding (e.g., | becomes %7C). For POST, this limit is 16K.
>
> If URL length is a problem, here are a few suggestions for shortening your URL:
>
> - If you are using a text encoding data format, remove leading zeros from numbers, remove trailing zeros after decimal points, and round or truncate the numbers after decimal points.
> - If that does not shorten the URL enough, use simple (1 character) or extended (2 character) encoding.
> - Sample data less frequently; i.e., reduce granularity.
> - Remove accoutrements and decorations, such as colors, labels, and styles, from your chart.

also found this but there doesn't seem to be an answer/solution.
http://groups.google.com/group/google-chart-api/browse_thread/thread/b47c1588b39d98ce

Answer (score 0):

In case it is a browser error - browsers have their maximum URL length limitations (IE 6/7 has 2,083 limit):

[What is the maximum length of a URL in different browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/417142/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-a-url)

Comment: I am calling this charts in my Android application.

Answer (score 0):

I'm getting HTTP 414 but my URL length is not an issue (it is 1881 characters), and I have tried both GET and POST.  My guess is that Google will also return this error when the chart you are requesting is too "expensive" to generate.

Answer (score 0):

A method that worked well for me was to divide all values by 10 or 20 and converting the results to int (no commas), but I kept the numbers on the axis. This way, it's a little less accurate but reduces the amount of characters used in the URL.

Code example:

```
$newSalesrank = $rank/20;
$rankdata .= intval($newSalesrank);
```

This solved my problem, I got no more "url too long" errors and it still looks good on my charts - because it still looked the same, the numbers just were simply scaled down.